# GUI for Apache/PHP on a Mac

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, php, apache-http-server, gui

Recently installed Snow Leopard on my Mac Mini. Something screwed up my Apache/PHP installation and it's now looking at a different library as localhost. The PHP installation also reset some of my earlier choices (i.e., turned cURL off, etc.).

Now, I know I can go around playing with a bunch of *.conf and *.ini files, but I wanted to know if there's a GUI available to control all those choices (a-la IIS Management applet in Windows)? Preferably a free one - this is for personal use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[webmin](http://www.webmin.com/osx.html) will work with OS X, and has some apache configuration options in it, I'm not sure about PHP. A word of warning, it's not exclusively apache configuration there are lots of other system settings can be changed through webmin.

I must admit, I don't use it myself but have heard good things about webmin.

There are also some useful tools as part of OS X Server, but I'm guessing you're using regular OS X so they won't be available.

Answer (score 2):

> a GUI [..] a-la IIS Management applet in Windows

Not an answer to your question, but especially when moving things from one server to another (like you kind of did when you installed Snow Leopard), or when taking things from a test machine to a production machine, I think you'll eventually love the configuration files.

In the IIS management console there's all kind of settings on many different screens, or hidden behind some "Advanced" button. One cannot get an overview of all current settings. And even worse, with each new version of IIS (even with a Service Pack) a few defaults might change, which one will not notice unless going through all the screens and buttons.

For Apache you can see and edit all settings in a few files.

So, and I am not trying to be funny: a good text editor might be the best GUI you'll find!

(I have written IIS configuration manuals that got outdated faster than I could create new screen captures; for Apache I'd just copy the relevant parts of some configuration files and that would be it.)

Comment: +1 reminds of me of the many, many times people have changed IIS settings on servers I look after without any real version / change control. Being able to use diff against a text file is a walk in the park by comparison

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Zend Server Community Edition for the Mac.  It's quite nice, and does everything through a clean GUI:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/

Comment: Thanks. But is there a solution that won't require installing a new environment - just one app to solve the issues in the existing one?